# How to delete a device node of disk by program

Tags: windows, device, hard-drive

I am developing the Windows program that removes specified disk from Windows system.
The action of "removing" does NOT mean unplugging HDD "physically".
It means that the program removes a disk from device node managed by OS.
"disk" what I'm saying is the disk that is managed by disk.sys(PhysicalDrive0, PhysicalDrive1..)

By the way, on usual Linux system, it can be done with a command like below.

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/delete
```

I want to do same thing as above on Windows by program.

Once I have tried to do it by removing a disk in DeviceManager.
Actually this way could remove USB disk, but this way could not remove SATA disk without rebooting OS. 
I want to do it without rebooting.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `WMI` might help you:

```
wmic logicaldisk delete (check with /? how to use it)
```

In order to know which ones you have now, launch the following first:

```
wmic logicaldisk list brief
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I didn't know that. 

Howwever `wmic logicaldisk` seems to manage volume(C:,D:) and `wmic diskdrive` seems to correspond to the "disk" I said.

So then I tried to perform this command.

    `wmic diskdrive where DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2" delete`

But it wasn't done normally(error occurred)

Although the error message is not English in my environment, it means that the operation isn't supported by the provider.

Comment: Generally `WMIC` commands are launched from a command-prompt. Did you start the command-prompt as administrator?